# Como contar valores nulos en SQL?

Tags: sql, null, google-bigquery

Estoy ocupando una base de datos en SQL y hay una columna que se llama "region", esta columna tiene valores nulos y quiero contarlos. Actualmente no sé mucho sobre SQL(Estoy aprendiendo lo basico). Hice un codigo que tiene cierta logica para mi, pero no funciona, alguien me podria explicar por qué?

```
SELECT count(CS.region) AS Null_Region
FROM  `bigquery-public-data.world_bank_intl_education.country_summary` AS CS
WHERE CS.region is null
```

Cuando ejecuto el codigo me cuenta 0 casillas. Sé que podemos usar algo como...

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN CS.region IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
FROM `bigquery-public-data.world_bank_intl_education.country_summary` AS CS
```

Pero solo quiero saber por qué mi codigo no funciona :((

Y solo por diversion, Si sabes otra manera de contar estas celdas, comenta :)

Comment: Hi. spanish is the official language for this site. please translate the question, if not it could be close.

Comment: Si traduces la pregunta, con gusto comparto la respuesta que es muy sencilla.

Comment: @LuisCazares en que sql es?

Comment: No importa realmente, ya que es un comportamiento del SQL estándar.

Comment: Esta en español ahora :))

Comment: Estoy ocupando el SQL de BigQuery

Comment: Toda la parte en ingles, esta de mas.. Este sitio es solo en español. por favor, vuelve a editar, y deja solo en español. Para ingles, tenes otro sitio que es en ingles...

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: super, gracias por los consejos 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Esto pasa debido a que las funciones de agregado omiten los valores nulos. Para poder contar los valores nulos de una columna, no le puedes pasar un valor que desde el inicio sabes que es nulo y por lo tanto será ignorado.

Por lo tanto, para hacer el conteo de una forma sencilla usando `COUNT()`, solo necesitas poner una expresión adecuada dentro de los paréntesis. Normalmente, sería un asterisco para decir que quieres contar la fila, pero una constante o una columna que no admita nulos puede funcionar.

```
SELECT count(*) AS Null_Region_Asterisco,
       count(1) AS Null_Region_Constante,
       count(country_code) AS Null_Region_Columna
FROM  `bigquery-public-data.world_bank_intl_education.country_summary` AS CS
WHERE CS.region is null
```

Comment: Perfecto, ya me quedo claro. Graciaas Luis